# Parsing Json String in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Json String returned from a web api and stored in a var using JObject.Parse(result);

```
"{\"Status\":\"0\",\"Message\":\"OK\",\"Count\":\"2\",\"MethodLog\":[{\"ApplicationName\":\"MobileGeneral\",\"CompanySN\":\"0897001\",\"MethodLogCount\":12,\"MethodAccessRefusedCount\":0},{\"ApplicationName\":\"MobileGrain\",\"CompanySN\":\"0897123\",\"MethodLogCount\":900,\"MethodAccessRefusedCount\":0}]}"
```

I have already created required classes in my workspace:

```
{
public class MethodLogJson
{
    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Count")]
    public string Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MethodLog")]
    public List<MethodLog> MethodLog { get; set; }
}
public class MethodLog
{
    [JsonProperty("ApplicationName")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CompanySN")]
    public string CompanySerial { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MethodLogCount")]
    public string MethodLogCnt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MethodAccessRefusedCount")]
    public string MethodAccessRefusedCnt { get; set; }
}
}
```

In my controller I am using:

```
var resObj = JObject.Parse(result);
var methodLog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MethodLogJson<MethodLog>>(resObj);
```

But it does not help. Shows me Non-generic Type cannot be used with type arguments. :( Help people!!

Comment: Well yes, `MethodLogJson` is a non-generic type - so `MethodLogJson<MethodLog>` makes no sense. Try just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MethodLogJson>(resObj)`

Comment: @JonSkeet now it Shows: "the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the JObject.Parse, simply deserialize the string into a MethodLogJson without type parameters.

```
MethodLogJson m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MethodLogJson>(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a type argument to a class that doesn't take type arguments.  Change

```
var methodLog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MethodLogJson<MethodLog>>(resObj);
```

to

```
var methodLog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MethodLogJson>(resObj);
```

Comment: Shows me : the best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments.

Comment: What does the code for your controller action look like?

Comment: @Ninja9 You need to pass the JSON string to the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and not the `JObject` (see the answer posted by @parachutinturtle)

Comment: Thank you @Bun I have already implemented parachutingturtle 's code in my controller and that is exactly what I want. thank you everyone!